# Wordpress multisite domain

Tags: multisite

I've been running a multisite in WP and now struggling to get a 2nd domain running.
I am not looking to have 1.example.com and example.com or example.com/ex
I have 2 separate names, example.com and website.com.
Is this possible in WordPress? Or should I detach the Multisite and run 2 whole separate wordpress installations from the same machine?

Comment: Yes, this is possible. You used to have to set up a plugin do to this but nowadays I think you can just set up the multisite as either subdomain or subdirectory and then edit the URL in the blog settings afterwards to be a custom domain. Hopefully someone can be more definitive.

Answer (score 1):

As @Rup points out in a comment, this is possible in WordPress, natively since version 4.5.

From [the documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/):

> WordPress multisite subsites may be mapped to a non-network top-level domain. This means a site created as subsite1.networkdomain.com, can be mapped to show as domain.com. This also works for subdirectory sites, so networkdomain.com/subsite1 can also appear at domain.com. Before setting up domain mapping, make sure your network has been correctly set up, and subsites can be created without issues.

[Read More](https://wordpress.org/support/article/wordpress-multisite-domain-mapping/)

**Note:** You'll need to make sure your DNS servers point to the right place, etc. WordPress doesn't manage DNS for you.